# Service implementation object was not Intialization in CoreWcf

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, corewcf

I receive the following error message

**The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available.**  at CoreWCF.Dispatcher.TaskMethodInvoker.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] inputs)
 at CoreWCF.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.<>c__DisplayClass71_0.<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
 at CoreWCF.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeAsync(MessageRpc rpc)

Please find below code for your reference.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddServiceModelServices().AddServiceModelConfigurationManagerFile("Web.config");
        services.AddServiceModelMetadata();

        services.AddSingleton<IServiceBehavior, UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior>();

        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
            loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights("xxxxxxxxxxx930939xxxx");
        });

        services.AddSingleton<ILoggingContractResolver, LoggingContractResolver>();


        IMapper mapper = SappoApiAutoMapperConfiguration.Configure().CreateMapper();

        services.AddSingleton<IMessageStoreFactory, AzureBlobMessageStoreFactory>();

        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IOutboundSappoLogger<>), typeof(OutboundSappoLogger<>));
        services.AddSingleton<IBlobStorageSettingsHelper, BlobStorageSettingsHelper>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBlobClientFactory, BlobClientFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceBusFactory>(ctx =>
        {
            return new ServiceBusFactory();
        });
        services.AddTransient<IShipperAsnService, ShipperAsnService>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }


        app.UseServiceModel(serviceBuilder =>
        {
            serviceBuilder.AddService<ShipperAsnService>(serviceOptions =>
            {
                serviceOptions.DebugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

            }).AddServiceEndpoint<ShipperAsnService, IShipperAsnService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "/ShipperAsnService.svc");
            serviceBuilder.ConfigureServiceHostBase<ShipperAsnService>(serviceHost =>
            {
                var behavior = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
                if (behavior == null)
                {
                    behavior = new ServiceBehaviorAttribute();
                    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
                }
                behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
                behavior.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple;
                behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
            });

        });
    }

}
```

IShipperAsnService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IShipperAsnService
    {
       [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        Task<ServiceResponse> ActionAsync(ShipperAsnRequest shipperBrnAsnRequest);
    }
```

ShipperAsnService.cs

```
public class ShipperAsnService : BaseShipperService<ShipperAsnRequest, OutboundShipperAsnServiceDto>, IShipperAsnService
{
    public ShipperAsnService(
        IMessageStoreFactory messageStoreFactory,
        IServiceBusFactory serviceBusFactory,
        IMapper mapper,
        IOutboundSappoLogger<ShipperAsnService> log)
        : base(messageStoreFactory, serviceBusFactory, mapper, DestinationApi.SAPPOAsn, log)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<ServiceResponse> ActionAsync(ShipperAsnRequest shipperBrnAsnRequest)
    {
        return await base.ActionAsync(shipperBrnAsnRequest);
    }
}
```

[image]

I am struggling to fix it. I want to resolve this issue.

Comment: <Message>The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available.</Message>
                    <StackTrace>   at CoreWCF.Dispatcher.TaskMethodInvoker.InvokeAsync(Object instance, Object[] inputs)&#xD;
   at CoreWCF.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass71_0.&lt;&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#xD;
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---&#xD;
   at CoreWCF.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeAsync(MessageRpc rpc)&#xD;

Comment: Please check with your Service contracts, try :`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")] public interface IShipperAsnService`

Comment: Besides what's your version of asp.net core have used? I see you use startup.cs, do you separate it from Program.cs  or what ?

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue and you could try to add

```
services.AddSingleton<ShipperAsnService>();
```

in the ConfigureServices method. The credit goes to [Carlos Pons and this blog entry](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/modernize-wcf-legacy-app-using-corewcf/)

It even seems unnecessary to register the interface implementation for the service with this line

```
services.AddTransient<IShipperAsnService, ShipperAsnService>();
```

At least in my own case.

If you don't need a Singleton service you can either use AddTransient or leave the registration out alltogether according to [this](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/issues/56#issuecomment-546519139) comment.

Comment: Dude this was it! registering the service as it self! seriously like all day trying to figure this bs out. and thanks for also pointing out the comment and Carlos Pons blog really useful 

Cheers to you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using CoreWCF.

CoreWCF will try get the WCF service instance first in DI, but Core WCF just try get it by Service Type, It doesn't care the interface of service in this step. So if you add your service as .NET way, in the DI container, you just can use the interface to get service instance, but Core WCF will get null.

Once Core WCF can't get the service instance by service type, it will back to WCF way to use the constructor with no parameters.

See: https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/issues/533